# dsa still supported for ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssl

I have an old id_dsa ssh key that I'd like to keep for passwordless ssh to my test machines, but recently it stopped working for ssh. "Recently" includes upgrading from SuSE Leap 42.2 -> 42.3 -> 15.0. My question is if the following is a mistake on my side, a bug, or intended:

```
b@e:~> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0h-fips  27 Mar 2018
b@e:~> ssh-keygen -tdsa -f id_dsa_test
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in id_dsa_test.
Your public key has been saved in id_dsa_test.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:6FAgJTbbKgccBg06364z2ATph0Zs+8rsmda7njArnk8 b@e
The key's randomart image is:
+---[DSA 1024]----+
|+==.o            |
...
|=.%+.            |
|=@=Oo            |
+----[SHA256]-----+
b@e:~> openssl dsa -text -noout -in id_dsa_test
read DSA key
Private-Key: (1024 bit)
priv:
    10:dd:1f:...
    aa:af:5b:ad:06
pub: 
    22:c4:ff:...
    52:70:4d:8b:4d:cf:ca:53:2f
Q:   
    00:82:6f:...
    5e:1c:20:03:3d:6b
G:   
    4d:18:15:...
    43:8e:d5:1f:7f:59:f7:e6
```

So far, so good, but:

```
b@e:~> ssh-keygen -Lf id_dsa_test
id_dsa_test:1: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:2: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:3: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:4: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:5: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:6: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:7: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:8: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:9: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:10: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:11: invalid key: invalid format
id_dsa_test:12: invalid key: invalid format
```

And ssh always falls back to password authentication, no matter if I use my original or the newly created certificate ...

Comment: Haha, after `ssh -v root@test` I noticed the output **debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/b/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes**. Adding "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss" to /etc/ssh_config solved my original problem and passwordless ssh works again ... What remains is the bad ssh-keygen -L output (not only for dsa keys).

Comment: It's more than acceptable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-L` option for ssh-keygen is intended for OpenSSH certificates, not plain keys. Try using `ssh-keygen -lf id_dsa_test` instead, that should produce the output you expect.

Also, support for DSA is deprecated, as you discovered. So for now, you need to explicitly make updates to continue supporting DSA, but at some point, OpenSSH is planning on fully removing support for these key types.

You should probably update your ssh_config file to use "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss" so that it adds the key type back to the default list, rather than replace it with a list that only contains ssh-dss. This is especially true if that was added to /etc/ssh_config, and not to ~/.ssh/config (under a Host block).

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys